# BCP Import incorrect settings - 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

I am having issue that is exactly same as what is described in this link - http://db-pub.com/forum-80219493/bcp-in-import-errors.html .

The only difference is the table in my case doesn't even have any indexed view on it. It contains only one column which has an identity key as primary key.

I have tried -q option via export and tried importing the data, facing the same issue. Any help? I am trying to import in SQL Server 2008 R2 server.

Answer (score 0):

We have found out the issue. It was arising due to one column that was having PERSISTED constraint in it. Upon removal of the constraint imports are occurring successfully.